# How to set a CSS font-family using JQuery when the font name has a space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-family

I'm trying to set the `font-family` property using the JQuery `css` method and running into a problem when the font name has a space.

No matter how I quote or don't quote the font name, the element ends up like:

```
<h1 style="font-family: "Comic Sans"">Title Text</h1>
```

with nested double quotes.

```js
var font_family = 'Arial Black';
var $title_template = $('<h1>Title Text</h1>');
var $title;

console.log(font_family)
$title = $title_template.clone().css({'font-family': font_family});
$('body').append($title)

font_family = "'Arial Black'";
console.log(font_family);
$title = $title_template.clone().css({'font-family': font_family});
$('body').append($title)

font_family = '"Arial Black"';
console.log(font_family);
$title = $title_template.clone().css({'font-family': font_family});
$('body').append($title)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 style="font-family: 'Arial Black'">Title Text</h1>
```

Comment: Font names with spaces need quotes around them.
You need to use:
`jQuery('body').css({'font-family': '"Comic Sans"', 'font-weight': 500}); `

Comment: I know next to nothing about fonts, but are you sure you have a font-family of "Comic Sans" normally? It works for me only when I use "Comic Sans MS" instead of "Comic Sans".

Comment: have you included font files in your page?

Comment: @CertainPerformance -- good catch. I changed it to Ariel Black. Now it seems to work. I'm still a bit confused because it still has the nested double quotes, but "works."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking at the font in the developer options in your browser, don't be alarmed that it looks like poorly nested quotes: `<h1 style="font-family: "Arial Black"">Title Text</h1>`. That's just how the browser chooses to render the Style property of that element. The style is actually being applied, and the font family is being set properly.

If you look at the properties of the DOM element (in Chrome DevTools for example), you'll see that the value of font-family is `"Arial Black"`. The extra quotes are there because of the space in the font name. And if you change the first line of your JS from `var font_family = 'Arial Black` to `var font_family = 'Arial'`, the value of font-family will appear simply as `Arial` (without quotes).

PS - To get "Comic Sans" to appear I had to use "Comic Sans MS", the proper name of the infamous font.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. As it happens, I was using google fonts and I had broken the link text into one font on each line. Strangely, the fonts without spaces in their names were loading fine in that format, but the ones with spaces weren't. So the nested double quotes was a red herring. With them all on one line everything works fine.  But now I know for sure that the nested double quotes isn't a problem.